# Thinktecture IdentityServer v3 and SAML

Tags: saml, thinktecture-ident-server

Does Thinktecture IdentityServer V3 has support for SAML or does it only support OAuth?

Answer (score 12):

IdentityServer v3 supports any Katana-compatible Owin middleware for authentication. With a compatible middleware for SAML2 such as [Kentor.AuthServices](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices) IdentityServer 3 can authenticate against external SAML2 Identity Providers with Idsrv acting as a SAML2 Service Provider. I wrote a [blog post](http://coding.abel.nu/2015/01/saml2-for-thinktecture-identityserver-3-with-kentor-authservices/) on how to do it.

There's also a plugin interface which would allow IdentityServer v3 to act as a SAML2 Identity Provider but as far as I know there's no implementation available.

Comment: It's been almost 2 years. Is there any progress on the new tools to use SAML 2 with Identityserver3 ? I liked Kentor.AuthServices but would like to know if there are any other such tools.

Answer (score 2):

There is [Owin middleware to support the SAML protocol](https://github.com/elerch/SAML2/) you can use with IdentityServer v3. It does not yet support all flows but it is being used in a couple implementations. Full disclosure - I am the author of this code which was forked from a previous [SAML2 library on CodePlex](https://saml2.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Nope!  No SAML.

[leastPrivilege.com](http://leastprivilege.com/2015/01/25/identityserver3-1-0-0/)

In the article Dominick says... "Having spent a considerable amount of time in the WS*/SAML world, it became more and more apparent that these technologies are not a good match for the modern types of applications that we (and our customers) like to build."

They focused on OpenID Connect and OAuth2.

Comment: Didn't downvote because this was probably accurate two years ago. As of now there is a nuget package called IdentityServer3.WsFederation to enable this.

here's an article that should get you started:

https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Identity-Server-3-using-WS-Federation

Answer (score 1):

OpenID Connect, OAuth2, WS-Fed.

@DavidEdwards - no - IdentityServer2 has no SAML support OOTB.

I normally get around this by:

IdentityServer --> WS-Fed --> ADFS --> SAML --> IDP

Comment: In the readme.md file on the github page (https://github.com/IdentityServer/Thinktecture.IdentityServer2) it says  "Multiple protocols support (WS-Trust, WS-Federation, OAuth2, HTTP GET)
Multiple token support (SAML 1.1/2.0, JWT)"  Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: saml is a token type (assertions) and a protocol. The protocol is not supported.

Comment: @leastprivilege , After 2 years is this still the case?  I have implemented IdentityServer V3 as my identity provider but I have some old clients that use saml tokens. I want to accept their Saml tokens so they can have a seamless Single sign on experience into my app.  Are the libraries mentioned above a viable/recommended option for this?

Comment: @RayLoveless are you able to find out if IdentityServer 3 supports SAML. Its says `Support for external social identity providers like Google, Facebook etc, as well as integration for enterprise identity management systems via SAML and WS-Federation.`  https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/highLevelFeatures.html

Comment: @LP13, It's been a while since looked at the code from our implementation I believe we wrote some custom code to support a saml 2p client(salesforce).  Sorry I don't have access to the code anymore because it was for a past employer or I would look into it for you. sorry.

Comment: As per the post below, Kentor (now called Sustainsys) is an option. OOTB. no - no support.